# Yamaha CLP-295GP: adjust “program change” parameter

Tags: piano, midi, digital-piano

I have taken the position of Organist/Pianist at my church and have “inherited” the Yamaha Clavinova CLP-295GP.

I am in the process of hooking up the organ (1100+ pipe with MIDI) and Clavinova to PC so I can drive them, and ultimately accompany myself.

However I cannot find how to turn off the “Program Change” parameter on the Clav. I have found manuals/key maps for various other models, but not the CLP-295GP, and they don’t translate. The internal voices have been setup for the acoustics of the church so I want to use them, rather than whatever voice the midi file sends.

Does anyone know what the correct keys are, and will they stay set on power cycle?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not just change the PC in the midi files to the preferred ones?

Comment: @Tetsujin I had tried multiple voices but none were the same as the main grand piano, and mellow grand piano voices. I actually found the setting buried in the functions by going through each item. Makes a huge difference to sound and also means I don’t have to edit every midi file.